# how can i add two strings in Autocomplete label

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

This is my query of Autocompletion:

```
$studentsQuery = $conn->query('select s.student_fname,s.student_lname as label,blahhh.....);
```

from the query i am getting result as `student_lname` in input field value because i wrote it as a `label`

My question is how can i add `student_fname`, `student_lname` in label..?

**Example:**
I have a name like Mohammad(`student_fname`) Waheed(`student_lname`)
current result is "waheed" But i want "Mohammad Waheed".

Comment: I need like this:   `s.student_fname.student_lname` as `label`

Comment: @Gulshan Assalamualikum i think you have not understood my question. And there is no echo it is autocomplete.! And i can not seperate like you said it will messedup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concat() function is used to combine multiple strings:

```
select concat(s.student_fname, ' ', s.student_lname) as label ...
```

Comment: You are awesome man thank you..! it worked like a magic. @ffork